# Flex column - align div vertically to middle and another div vertically to bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

How to align a div vertically to middle and another div vertically to bottom inside a flex column?

Expected result: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5XIb.png]

Comment: Your div has a specific height?

Comment: @avrilalejandro the flex column has a specific height

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first-item {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-item">First</div>
  <div class="second-item">Second</div>
</div>
```

That should do it. Then the second item should be pushed to the bottom while the first item stays in the middle. A pure flexbox solution not using absolute positioning.

Comment: Awesome. Been looking all day for this. Worked 100%

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [line-height](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) property with the same height value

```css
.parent{
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;

  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
}
.parent div{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  test
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use flexbox, you can't use line-height in multi-line text...

Comment: @Rob Please add code in your question

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
    height: 150px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.two{
    align-self: flex-end;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div>test</div>
   <div class="two">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: It should be equal to https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5XIb.png

Comment: you mean the width is more?